# How to compute k largest eigen values on GPU?

Tags: cuda, eigenvector, eigenvalue, jacket

I'm working on parallel algorithm for spectral clustering for which I need to calculate K largest eigen values.I'm using Jacket plugin for Matlab but sadly it doesn't support EIGS function in matlab(It is not able to calculate K eigen values in parallel)Can anyone please suggest some other tool/library to do this task on GPU?Or Can I still do this in GPU assisted Matlab?

Comment: Numerically speaking, you could write a GPU implementation of the QR algorithm for the eigenvalue problem. Alternatively look for a GPU-compatible version of any method presented here:http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa04/cse252c/sakumar.pdf .I'm not aware of any ready-to-use gpu-library for the eigenvalue problem

Comment: EIGS is for sparse matrices.  Do you require sparse matrices or can you use EIG (which Jacket supports) for dense matrices?

Comment: There is CULA which can do eigenvalue problems allright, but only in the dense version.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You are right.  Note that Jacket includes CULA for these problems, so when you're using Jacket you get CULA-powered functions too.

Comment: I tried using EIG function in Matlab but it says Empty Input.My matrix is relatively sparse so i guess EIG is not working

Comment: EIGS is not supported in Matlab...how can I acheive this task?

Answer (score 2):

I can't respond to chemeng in the comment list above, but I know of a pretty good paper on GPU-based QR-decomposition: http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~mrichard/Kerr_Campbell_Richards_QRD_on_GPUs.pdf

Also, does the svd() command work for jacket? The singular values are just the squares of the eigenvalues.